How to run multiple test suites simultaneously with different numbers of workers?
Scripts from package.json:
"scripts": {
       "all": "npm-run-all debug1 debug2 merge-reports",
       "debug1": "npx playwright test --grep @debug1 --workers=1",
       "debug2": "npx playwright test --grep @debug2 --workers=3",
       "merge-reports": "npx playwright merge-reports --reporter html ./blob-report",
   },

I need a script that will run all tests and adjust the number of workers depending on the tag. As a result, I should get one combined report. With the current implementation, I only get a report for the debug2.
I tried using "merge-reports", but when the execution of the 'all' script reaches "merge-reports", the report from "debug2" overwrites "debug1", and as a result, I only get the report from "debug2".
playwright.config.ts:
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

require('dotenv').config();

export default defineConfig({
    timeout: 160000,
    testDir: './tests',
    fullyParallel: true,
    expect: { timeout: 10000, toHaveScreenshot: { maxDiffPixels: 200 } },
    workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
    reporter: 'blob',

    use: {
        headless: true,
        baseURL: process.env.BASEURL,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        locale: 'ru-Ru',
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
        video: {
            mode: 'off',
            //size: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
        },
    },

    projects: [
        {
            name: 'desktop',
            testDir: './tests',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 } },
        },
    ],
});

